# Node JS Serverless Api running fine in offline mode but not when deployed to AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have written a code to stop and start the ec2 instances. I am  passing data through postman in json  like this to the post api in node JS.

```
{
    "action" : "stop",
    "instance_id" : "i-xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
}
```

This is my code.

```
"use strict";

require("dotenv").config();

// load the SDK for JavaScript
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
// Set the region
AWS.config.update({ region: "us-west-2" });

// Create EC2 service object
var ec2 = new AWS.EC2({ apiVersion: "2016-11-15" });

module.exports.trigger = async (event) => {
  const body = JSON.parse(event.body);

  let id = body.instance_id;
  let action = body.action;

  var params = {
    InstanceIds: [id],
    DryRun: true,
  };

  if (action.toUpperCase() === "START") {
    // Call EC2 to start the selected instances
    ec2.startInstances(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err && err.code === "DryRunOperation") {
        console.log("inside start");
        params.DryRun = false;
        ec2.startInstances(params, function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
            // issue = err;
          } else if (data) {
            console.log("Success", data.StartingInstances);
            // out = data.StartingInstances;
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log("You don't have permission to start instances.");
      }
    });
  } else if (action.toUpperCase() === "STOP") {
    // Call EC2 to stop the selected instances
    ec2.stopInstances(params, function (err, data) {
      if (err && err.code === "DryRunOperation") {
        params.DryRun = false;
        ec2.stopInstances(params, function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error", err);
            // issue = err;
          } else if (data) {
            console.log("Success", data.StoppingInstances);
            // out = data.StoppingInstances;
          }
        });
      } else {
        console.log("You don't have permission to stop instances", err);
      }
    });
  }

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(
      {
        message: "Go Serverless v3.0! Your function executed successfully!",
        input: event,
      },
      null,
      2
    ),
  };
};
```

This code is working fine when i am doing sls offline and running the code locally in my localhost. But when I deploy the code to lambda . The code is running fine but it is not starting or stopping the instance".

I don't know what could possibly be the reason.

it is not giving any error also . I don't know why it is returning the response without even executing the steps in between.

Comment: Hi,
Can you share the lambda log from cloudwatch? I see you put some console.log, that should give us some information about where is your program going.

Comment: `await ec2.stopInstances(params).promisify()`

Comment: Hi @brnaba . actually there is nothing coming up from those console.log.i think the script is not even executing that part. because if it executed then atleast some output should come from console.log in the cloudwatch logs.

Comment: hi @hoangdv . Sure let me try with that.

Comment: TypeError ec2.stopInstances(...).promisify is not a function.

Comment: hi @hoangdv . it is giving above error

Comment: @coderByChance, I think the idea was to do something like this: 
https://gist.github.com/eddmann/a9e404eb62056f77610f752606a2e504

Comment: @AnthonyB. . Yeah it worked like a charm. So by using  await and the promise my issue got resolved. Thanks a lot.

Comment: await ec2
      .stopInstances(params)
      .promise(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error", err);
          // issue = err;
        } else if (data) {
          console.log("Success", data.StoppingInstances);
          // out = data.StoppingInstances;
        }
      })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The resolution to this question was to use promises in the code.Something like this

```
await ec2
      .stopInstances(params)
      .promise(function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          console.log("Error", err);
          // issue = err;
        } else if (data) {
          console.log("Success", data.StoppingInstances);
          // out = data.StoppingInstances;
        }
      })
```